# how to solve the difference length between train and class

Tags: r, knn

i was trying to use KNN for titanic data, using R Below is my codes:

```
df = read_spss("Desktop/titanicTrain.sav")
    str(df)
    view(df)
    anyNA(df)
    df=na.omit(df)
    anyNA(df)

Survived.subset=df[c("Age","Sex","Survived")]
df1=df%>%
  select(Age,Sex,Survived)
view(df1)
view(Survived.subset)
df1=na.omit(df1)
#Normalize
normalize=function(x){
  return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))) }

Survived.subset.n=as.data.frame(lapply(Survived.subset[,1],normalize))
head(Survived.subset.n)
library(foreign)
set.seed(123)#to get the same random sample
dat.d=sample(1:nrow(Survived.subset.n),size=nrow(Survived.subset.n)*0.7,replace=FALSE)#random selection of 70% of data.
train.survived=Survived.subset[dat.d,]#70% training data
test.survived=Survived.subset[-dat.d,]# remaining 30% test data

train.survived_labels=Survived.subset[dat.d,3]
test.survived_labels=Survived.subset[-dat.d,3]
library(class)# class package as it carries KNN function

NROW(train.survived_labels)
knn.22=knn(train=train.survived, test= test.survived,cl=train.survived_labels,k=22)
knn.23=knn(train=train.survived, test= test.survived,cl=train.survived_labels,k=23)
```

But I received an error:

> Error in knn(train = train.survived, test = test.survived, cl =
> train.survived_labels,  :    'train' and 'class' have different
> lengths

Comment: Hi @Omid Mehrpour. It is very difficult to see what happens from all this code. It would be better to paste the output of `dput(train.survived)` and `dput(test.survived)` and `dput(train.survived_labels)` in your question, together with your last line of code (rather than all the code before). This allows to see the structure (and length) of your objects.

Comment: You need at the very least to offer str on `df`. It doesn't appear to resemble The `Titanic` data object which is all It makes no sense (to me anyway) to do this: `lapply(Survived.subset[,1],normalize)`  The first argument to `lapply` is a single column, so you are passing individual values to the `normalize` function. You should state what you intended for that operation to do. Most of the variables in the "titanic" datasets that I've ever seen are categorical and normalization makes no sense.

Comment: When you [edit] the question body (since you will get screamed at if you put data in Comments) , you should also add library calls to whatever package has your knn function as well as to pkg:dplyr. Otherwise your code throws errors. Get in the habit of testing your code on a clean workspace to find the missing packages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.